# docker-compose start "ERROR: No containers to start"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to use Docker Compose (with Docker Machine on Windows) to launch a group of Docker containers.

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  postgres:
    build: ./postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "4567:4567"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    ports:
       - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
       - postgres
```

`docker-compose build` runs successfully. When I run `docker-compose start` I get the following output:

```
Starting postgres ... done
Starting frontend ... done
Starting backend ... done
ERROR: No containers to start
```

I did confirm that the docker containers are not running. How do I get my containers to start?

Answer (score 232, accepted):

The issue here is that you haven't actually created the containers. You will have to create these containers before running them. You could use the `docker-compose up` instead, that will create the containers and then start them.

Or you could run `docker-compose create` to create the containers and then run the `docker-compose start` to start them.

Comment: What does `docker-compose build` do?

Comment: `docker-compose build` creates the images from your docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: Note that `docker-compose create` is deprecated. Use the `up` command with `--no-start` instead.

Answer (score 47):

The reason why you saw the error is that `docker-compose start` and `docker-compose restart` assume that the containers already exist.

If you want to build and start containers, use

```
docker-compose up
```

If you only want to build the containers, use

```
docker-compose up --no-start
```

Afterwards, `docker-compose {start,restart,stop}` should work as expected.

There used to be a `docker-compose create` command, but it is now deprecated in favor of `docker-compose up --no-start`.