# Docker is not recognizing a directory as directory in Arch Linux

Tags: docker, archlinux, manjaro

Basically, I'm getting this error when I try to create my containers:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:337: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:403: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/etc/timezone\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8864cea6615c7c165fce558661bf297c43ebf90f4de534ca9c9bd38f7af8b487/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8864cea6615c7c165fce558661bf297c43ebf90f4de534ca9c9bd38f7af8b487/merged/etc/timezone\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type.
```

No Idea why this is happening. It was working perfectly on Manjaro, but not working on Arch Labs.

Comment: Can you Update your question with Dockerfile and docker run command that you are performing. For a better understanding of your project.

Comment: By the way, It seems like a duplicate of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972812/are-you-trying-to-mount-a-directory-onto-a-file-or-vice-versa)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image used expects a directory at `/etc/timezone` that is not used on Arch Linux.

Expected `/etc/timezone` contents example:

```
Etc/UTC
```

Simply remove that bind mount from your command or docker-compose file. You need to set the timezone at in the container differently or find a way to keep the `/etc/timezone` file in sync with `/etc/localtime`.

`/etc/timezone` is a Solaris and Debian thing, I guess. It expects the timezone as a pair

```
Europe/Zürich
```