# Permission Denied on port when starting HDP Sandbox Proxy on Docker (Windows 10)

Tags: docker, hdp

I am getting the following error when trying to start sandbox-proxy (proxy-deploy.sh) on docker. 
Have tried reinstalling, rebooting, checking existing in use ports using netstat -a -n. Nothing helped.

```
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint sandbox-proxy (b710798aa75668908d359602541ed4d8a3da4e4b8b2856f5e779453ea296aeef): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:50111: unexpected error Permission denied
Error: failed to start containers: sandbox-proxy
```

Detailed snapshot of failure

[image]

Docker logs attempt as requested

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you share the output of `docker logs <containerName>`?
Also, do you have any service running at port 50111?

Comment: No other service or process using port 50111. Checked using netstat -anp tcp | grep 50111  and CurrPorts. Have added the attempt to fetch logs. It does not return anything using container id or name.

Comment: `docker ps -a` - Any other containers? Could you temporarily use another port to run a quick test?
`netcfg -d` - this will clean up all networking devices, and requires a reboot

Comment: Added. Have tried netcfg -d. Didn't help.

Comment: Didn't understand how to use another port to run a quick test.

Comment: I have shared the steps in the answer, you can refer to the same.

Comment: I have the same problem with port *2222*, again it's not used. Sometimes it's the port 15000. A docker restart can fix it some times. All the fixes I tried did not help, in my oppinion, because the ports are not in use and there is something else going on here.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the location where you saved the Docker deployment scripts – refer to [Deploy HDP Sandbox](https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/sandbox-deployment-and-install-guide/section/3/#deploy-hdp-sandbox) as an example. You will notice a new directory sandbox was created.

- Edit file sandbox/proxy/proxy-deploy.sh
- Modify conflicting port (first in keypair). For example, 6001:6001 to **16001**:6001
- Save/Exit the File
- Run bash script: bash sandbox/proxy/proxy-deploy.sh
- Repeat steps for continued port conflicts

More info : `https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/sandbox-deployment-and-install-guide/section/3/#port-conflict`

Comment: Did. Getting the following error now: 
docker.exe: invalid publish opts format (should be name=value but got '1080:1080'). This happens to be the first port on that file.

Comment: And when I revert the edit, it returns the original error. Strange. Does have something to do with the formatting?

Comment: Seems deleting a digit from the key, instead of adding works. But after resolving all conflicts, getting this error: OCI runtime create failed.
Also tracking this issue here: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3103

Comment: Following the solns. here didn't fix the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972812/are-you-trying-to-mount-a-directory-onto-a-file-or-vice-versa

Comment: Currently, you are on port number `50111`, and you changed it to `150111 ` - invalid port number. `65535` - is the max for port numbers.
`OCI runtime create failed ` - all of the error? No other information?

Update the port in your config file, the 1st part of it only - in the script. Quit docker and start it again.

Comment: Ok, so that explains why changing the key to a lower number worked. The detailed error is in the issue tracking link I shared above.

Comment: Given up. Couldn't get HDP sandbox to work with Docker and VBox. I have 16 GB ram on my machine. Thankfully, works with VMware, finally. Thanks for your time.