# Docker-compose version 3; why I am getting "not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

Context: I want to create a docker-compose to run ELK + Beats + Kafka for logging purposes.

I had successfully started this task and suddenly I decided to update docker-compose from version 2 to version 3. After that I keep getting:

```
ERROR: for kibana  Cannot start service kibana: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/host_mnt/c/Dockers/megalog-try-1/kibana.yml\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e1bf99bc19edf4bb68bfad5a76c1e6b9ac1b69f84af85767c2127fd1295c0536/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e1bf99bc19edf4bb68bfad5a76c1e6b9ac1b69f84af85767c2127fd1295c0536/merged/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Firstly I though it was because previous volume was impacting somehow then I deleted all volumes and previous containers. But it didn't fix it.

I read carefully [Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972812/are-you-trying-to-mount-a-directory-onto-a-file-or-vice-versa) and checked all suggestions but I didn't move forward. In my case, I am not using Oracle Virtual Box at all.

Any thing suggestion to check will be highly appreciatted.

All my docker-compose is:

```
version: '3'
services:
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.5.2
    volumes:
      - "./kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.5.2
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - "./esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.5.2
    volumes:
      - "./logstash.conf:/config-dir/logstash.conf"
    restart: always
    command: logstash -f /config-dir/logstash.conf
    ports:
      - "9600:9600"
      - "7777:7777"
    links:
      - elasticsearch
      - kafka1
      - kafka2
      - kafka3
  kafka1:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3
    links:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_HOURS: "168"
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_BYTES: "100000000"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT:  zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "log:3:3"
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'false'
  kafka2:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3
    links:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3
    ports:
      - "9093:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_HOURS: "168"
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_BYTES: "100000000"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT:  zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "log:3:3"
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'false'
  kafka3:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3
    links:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3
    ports:
      - "9094:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 3
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_HOURS: "168"
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_BYTES: "100000000"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT:  zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "log:3:3"
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'false'
  zoo1:
    image: elevy/zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      MYID: 1
      SERVERS: zoo1,zoo2,zoo3
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  zoo2:
    image: elevy/zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      MYID: 2
      SERVERS: zoo1,zoo2,zoo3
    ports:
      - "2182:2181"
  zoo3:
    image: elevy/zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      MYID: 3
      SERVERS: zoo1,zoo2,zoo3
    ports:
      - "2183:2181"
  filebeat:
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.5.2
    volumes:
      - "./filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml:ro"
      - "./apache-logs:/apache-logs"
    links:
      - kafka1
      - kafka2
      - kafka3
    depends_on:
      - apache
      - kafka1
      - kafka2
      - kafka3
  apache:
    image: lzrbear/docker-apache2-ubuntu
    volumes:
      - "./apache-logs:/var/log/apache2"
    ports:
      - "8888:80"
    depends_on:
      - logstash
```

IN case it is relevant, filebeat and kibana.yml are:

filebeat.yml

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- paths:
    - /apache-logs/access.log
  tags:
    - testenv
    - apache_access
  input_type: log
  document_type: apache_access
  fields_under_root: true

- paths:
    - /apache-logs/error.log
  tags:
    - testenv
    - apache_error
  input_type: log
  document_type: apache_error
  fields_under_root: true

output.kafka:
  hosts: ["kafka1:9092", "kafka2:9092", "kafka3:9092"]
  topic: 'log'
  partition.round_robin:
    reachable_only: false
  required_acks: 1
  compression: gzip
  max_message_bytes: 1000000
```

kibana.yml

```
server.name: kibana
server.host: "0"
elasticsearch.url: http://elasticsearch:9200
xpack.monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled: false
```

The whole log is:

```
C:\Dockers\megalog-try-1>docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                      NAMES
3366ee0766a8        lzrbear/docker-apache2-ubuntu               "apachectl -D FOREGR…"   16 hours ago        Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:8888->80/tcp                                       megalog-try-1_apache_1
6fcdcbf8e75e        docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.5.2   "/usr/local/bin/dock…"   16 hours ago        Up 15 seconds       0.0.0.0:7777->7777/tcp, 5044/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9600->9600/tcp   megalog-try-1_logstash_1
dd854b18aa80        elevy/zookeeper:latest                      "/entrypoint.sh zkSe…"   16 hours ago        Up About a minute   2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 9010/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2183->2181/tcp       megalog-try-1_zoo3_1
498c3d3132fd        elevy/zookeeper:latest                      "/entrypoint.sh zkSe…"   16 hours ago        Up About a minute   2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 9010/tcp       megalog-try-1_zoo1_1
555279c42b9d        elevy/zookeeper:latest                      "/entrypoint.sh zkSe…"   16 hours ago        Up About a minute   2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 9010/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2182->2181/tcp       megalog-try-1_zoo2_1

C:\Dockers\megalog-try-1>docker-compose up -d
Creating megalog-try-1_zoo3_1          ... done                                                                         Creating megalog-try-1_zoo2_1          ... done                                                                         Creating megalog-try-1_zoo1_1          ... done                                                                         Creating megalog-try-1_elasticsearch_1 ... done                                                                         Creating megalog-try-1_kibana_1        ... error                                                                        Creating megalog-try-1_kafka2_1        ...
Creating megalog-try-1_kafka1_1        ...
Creating megalog-try-1_kafka3_1        ...

ERROR: for megalog-try-1_kibana_1  Cannot start service kibana: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/host_mnt/c/Dockers/megalog-try-1/kibana.yml\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e1bf99bc19edf4bb68bfad5a76c1e6b9ac1b69f84afCreating megalog-try-1_kafka2_1        ... done                                                                         Creating megalog-try-1_kafka1_1        ... done                                                                         Creating megalog-try-1_kafka3_1        ... done                                                                         Creating megalog-try-1_logstash_1      ... done                                                                         Creating megalog-try-1_apache_1        ... done                                                                         Creating megalog-try-1_filebeat_1      ... error                                                                        
ERROR: for megalog-try-1_filebeat_1  Cannot start service filebeat: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/host_mnt/c/Dockers/megalog-try-1/filebeat.yml\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bc908c4b9e42c9c3c0a0f2f88387ca1dee1d20b341d18175df4678136a4e7730/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bc908c4b9e42c9c3c0a0f2f88387ca1dee1d20b341d18175df4678136a4e7730/merged/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type

ERROR: for filebeat  Cannot start service filebeat: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/host_mnt/c/Dockers/megalog-try-1/filebeat.yml\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bc908c4b9e42c9c3c0a0f2f88387ca1dee1d20b341d18175df4678136a4e7730/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bc908c4b9e42c9c3c0a0f2f88387ca1dee1d20b341d18175df4678136a4e7730/merged/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type

ERROR: for kibana  Cannot start service kibana: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/host_mnt/c/Dockers/megalog-try-1/kibana.yml\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e1bf99bc19edf4bb68bfad5a76c1e6b9ac1b69f84af85767c2127fd1295c0536/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e1bf99bc19edf4bb68bfad5a76c1e6b9ac1b69f84af85767c2127fd1295c0536/merged/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

*** Edited

I could move forward by:

1 - deleting all images. After that I got this other error message

```
ERROR: for elasticsearch  Cannot start service elasticsearch: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/c/Dockers/megalog-try-1/esdata': mkdir /host_mnt/c/Dockers/megalog-try-1/esdata: file exists
```

2 - then I read somewhere someone saying this weird solution: remove D drive from share files, save, restart, share again, save and restart. Well then it worked. Honestly I don't consider this the answer to my above question mainly beacause it was working wiht docker-compose version 2 and now I am jumping from one error to another. Either I did something wrong in docker-compose file or there is some concept I am missing ( I can't delete images and remove shared drive on daily base).

3 - now I can't log in Kibana with "Kibana server is not ready yet" and this message from Docker

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-02-04T04:03:53Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":6,"message":"No living connections"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-02-04T04:03:56Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":6,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://localhost:9200/"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-02-04T04:03:56Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":6,"message":"No living connections"}
```

Here is the whole console from PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Users\Cast> $images = docker images -a -q
PS C:\Users\Cast> foreach ($image in $images) { docker image rm $image -f }
```

...

new error:

```
C:\Dockers\megalog-try-1>docker-compose up -d
megalog-try-1_zoo3_1 is up-to-date
megalog-try-1_zoo2_1 is up-to-date
Starting megalog-try-1_elasticsearch_1 ...
Starting megalog-try-1_elasticsearch_1 ... error                                                                                                                            Starting megalog-try-1_kafka2_1        ...
Starting megalog-try-1_kafka1_1        ...
Starting megalog-try-1_kafka3_1        ...
Starting megalog-try-1_kafka2_1        ... done                                                                                                                             Starting megalog-try-1_kafka1_1        ... done                                                                                                                             Starting megalog-try-1_kafka3_1        ... done                                                                                                                             
ERROR: for elasticsearch  Cannot start service elasticsearch: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/c/Dockers/megalog-try-1/esdata': mkdir /host_mnt/c/Dockers/megalog-try-1/esdata: file exists
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

After removing C drive/restart/share again C drive/restart Docker

```
C:\Dockers\megalog-try-1>docker-compose up -d
megalog-try-1_zoo3_1 is up-to-date
megalog-try-1_zoo2_1 is up-to-date
megalog-try-1_zoo1_1 is up-to-date
Starting megalog-try-1_elasticsearch_1 ... done                                                                                                                             Starting megalog-try-1_kafka2_1        ... done                                                                                                                             Starting megalog-try-1_kafka1_1        ... done                                                                                                                             Starting megalog-try-1_kafka3_1        ... done                                                                                                                             Creating megalog-try-1_kibana_1        ... done                                                                                                                             Creating megalog-try-1_logstash_1      ... done                                                                                                                             Creating megalog-try-1_apache_1        ... done                                                                                                                             Creating megalog-try-1_filebeat_1      ... done                                                                                                                             
C:\Dockers\megalog-try-1>
```

By the way, I wasn't get issues at all when using docker-compose version 2. So I am wondering if docker-compose version isn't the issue.

Comment: Check out this answer.. Worked for me after some updates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972812/are-you-trying-to-mount-a-directory-onto-a-file-or-vice-versa