# Docker volumes reconnizing file as directory?

Tags: bash, docker, nginx

I am building docker deployment scripts for my microservices right now.
Following script gives me an error:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
DEPLOYMENT_PATH=$(pwd)
echo "NGINX deployment start"
docker run --name webserver -v $DEPLOYMENT_PATH/configuration/config.json:/usr/share/nginx/json/config.json \
                            -v $DEPLOYMENT_PATH/configuration/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
                            -p 9999:80 \
                            --rm \
                            nginx:1.19.6
echo "Nginx deployed"
```

error msg:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:459: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:59: mounting "/home/polito/Projects/magister-media/fahrschule/compose/dev/deployment/nginx/configuration/config.json" to rootfs at "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/01e6399a1a95710406183f7a13b32b5c362795fc3b50c08316540a31afc080d4/merged/usr/share/nginx/json/config.json" caused: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type.
Nginx deployed
```

following the following article:
[Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972812/are-you-trying-to-mount-a-directory-onto-a-file-or-vice-versa)

cat should return me "is a folder" but:

```json
~/Projects/magister-media/fahrschule/compose/dev/deployment$ cat /home/polito/Projects/magister-media/fahrschule/compose/dev/deployment/nginx/configuration/config.json
{
"jeopardyURL": "http://jeopardy:8080",
"waterlooURL":"http://waterloo:8080",
"keycloakTokenURL": "http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/drivingschool/protocol/openid-connect/token",
"keycloakClientId":"client_interface",
"keycloakClientSecret":"f06fe4b4-959f-4fb1-88e1-e7c4ad335743",
}
```

I have no clue why it's not working.
Thanks in advance,
Rosario

Comment: /home/polito/Projects/magister-media/fahrschule/compose/dev/deployment/nginx/configuration/config.json is a file maybe you want to mount /home/polito/Projects/magister-media/fahrschule/compose/dev/deployment/nginx/configuration/config.json" to rootfs at "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/01e6399a1a95710406183f7a13b32b5c362795fc3b50c08316540a31afc080d4/merged/usr/share/nginx/json which would be a directory?

Comment: But the error reads that i have to mount file to file, directory to directory, doesnt it?

Comment: docker run --name webserver -v $DEPLOYMENT_PATH/configuration/config.json:/usr/share/nginx/json/ \
                            -v $DEPLOYMENT_PATH/configuration/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \

this worked, no clue why its inconsistend in itself :(